# JS AudioContext oscillator - play more than one note at the same time (polyphony)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I created an oscillator, it actually can play single notes, but does not support two or more notes at the same time... how can I make it polyphonic?

```
$(window).load(function(){

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
ctx = new AudioContext();


$('path').on('touchstart mousedown', function(){
    $(this).css('fill','lime');
    noteON( $(this).attr('data-noteKEY') );
});
$('path').on('touchend mouseup', function(){
    $(this).css('fill','');
    noteOFF();
});


function noteON(noteKEY){
    osc = ctx.createOscillator();
    osc.type = 'sine';
    osc.frequency.value = noteKEY;

    osc.connect(ctx.destination);
    osc.start(0);
    //osc.connect(ctx.destination);
}

function noteOFF(){
     osc.stop(0);
}




});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like a real physical oscillator, you can't make a single oscillator output two separate pitches at the same time. You'll have to create one oscillator for each note you want to play. In your case it'd mean calling noteON twice with the separate noteKEY's you want to play at the same time.

Comment: Think of it like this - you won't have a single, global "osc" object when you want to play multiple notes.  You need to keep track of the playing notes and shut off the right ones.

Comment: Most polyphonic instruments still can only play a single note one time - like how a piano can only play middle C once at a time.  You might want to start with an array of notes, organized by note number.

Comment: What if you just made the oscillator play sin(x) + sin(2x) etc, can't it have multiple pitches then?

Comment: @pete - you could make it play multiple frequencies (harmonics). A sawtooth wave, for example, is made up of multiple sine waves at different frequencies. but you can only ask the oscillator to play one fundamental pitch (A, C, E etc.), if that makes sense?

Comment: But whatever combination of multiple notes you want to play can't you just add them all up? Like sin(x) + sin(1.1x); these are two sin of different frequency not related by overtones. If we want to make them swetooth then just also add all their overtones too. Will this not work as expected?